# Replacing a line of HTML with a database entry in a specific format

Tags: html, css, database, gallery

Before I explain the issue, I'd like to say I can code in HTML and CSS, so if you could offer a solution using those I'd be very pleased as I'll be fully able to customize it. Don't be afraid to use other languages though... Everything is welcome.

I've been searching around and I find a lot of similar questions with their respecive answers, but none quite matches what I need, so here I go.

I'm building a website for a person who sells handmade stuff. So far, the idea is to show a simple gallery of all the items in stock, but since this stock is constantly changing, I need a way to reflect these changes on the site, easily. Furthermore, it'd be even nicer if the seller himself could update the gallery without having to mess with the code on the actual site. Therefore, I plan to add a simple  tag in the main page, to be replaced with the data (as written by the seller), but displayed in a specific format I'll probably have to write in a separate file... This is where my problems begin.

So, the site has a /images folder where a single picture for each of the items is stored, and the file the seller is supposed to modify should include the item's name, filename of its picture, dimensions, price, a short description, and maybe the amount in stock. For each item. I don't even know what file format to use, since I'm not experienced with databases at all.

I need this data to be displayed in a particular pre-set way, with all the items clearly visible at once (using the browser's scrollbar), and without the need to edit any line of code anytime the amount of items varies as I can't just be watching the site at all times. I don't know how to do that, so any ideas would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: Here's a sample of a little placeholder code I made just to see how things could fit, in case it can be used.

```
<td class="thumb"><img src="images/tarjetas/2011/T01.JPG"><br><b>$2500 | Cód.: T01<br />16 x 11,5 cm<p /></b></td>
<td class="thumb"><img src="images/tarjetas/2011/T02.JPG"><br><b>$3500 | Cód.: T02<br />19 x 14 cm<p /></b></td>
<td class="thumb"><img src="images/tarjetas/2011/T03.JPG"><br><b>$2500 | Cód.: T03<br />17,5 x 12 cm<p /></b></td>
<td class="thumb"><img src="images/tarjetas/2011/T04.JPG"><br><b>$3500 | Cód.: T04<br />16 x 13 cm<p /></b></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As above. Learn php/mysqli. You need to create an admin side to the site where the owner can add entries to a database and then a client site side that customers can see which calls on the entries you added on the admin side.

It all depends on how much time you have as databases and php are not impossible to learn quickly. However if your taking money it will need to be secure. Look up pdo and prepared statements for your database interactions with MySQL.

If time is an issue just get a shopping cart plugin or use I think open source shopping carts into google etc and there will be plenty of choice.

You could also use a complete eccomerce solution like magento. Again type in CMS ecommerce software. There are great free ones.

Wordpress, joomla, Drupal are all open source CMS systems that also have shopping cart solutions (some paid). If you have time though learn php MySQL it open up so much functionality. I'm learning it myself and the database side of it opens up so many site possibilities.

Comment: Wow... It was really easy! Like the other guy said, I went to w3schools.com (which is where I learnt the basics for CSS too), and then, following your advice I took a quick glance at the PHP and MySQL guides... And with it I've actually 100% achieved the goal I described! Thanks a lot! Without you both I wouldn't have known where to even begin. Next steps are filling the database and setting up a proper interface for the owner... Learning is so much fun o:

Comment: You can create an admin page and get the site owner to log in to it. From here you can have an area for the admin to load new items and customers could not access.

Answer (score 0):

Then Why don't you go for open source free shopping cart there are lot many free shopping carts available like Avactis,prestashop,magento etc

Answer (score 0):

For this, my friend, you are going to have to learn forms and PHP. Go to a good and basic website like w3schools.com and start learning. I do not think such a thing would be possible without PHP as it is a **server-side language**. This means that it handles interaction with the server.
What I think you should do is add a link to another page where this a form that requires you to upload a picture and describe it.

Another thing is, if you want constant updating of the list of things you can buy, you might want to look into AJAX.